# Why is this infinite scroll using will_paginate not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I'm trying to get all posts from all users to be loaded via infinite scroll using will_paginate. Right now it's showing only the normal pagination. I am very confused. But then again, I'm a newbie. I'd appreciate any help.

index.html.erb:

```
<script>
$('#my-posts');
<% if @posts.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @posts %>');
<% else %>
  $(window).off('scroll');
  $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
</script>

<div id="my-posts">
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
#...posts and and their comments
    <% end %>
</div>

<div id="infinite-scrolling">
  <%= will_paginate %>
</div>
```

pagination.js.coffee (also tried pagination.coffee):

```coffee
jQuery ->
if $('#infinite-scrolling').size() > 0
  $(window).on 'scroll', ->
    more_posts_url = $('.pagination .next_page a').attr('href')
    if more_posts_url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 60
      $('.pagination').html('<p> loading <p>')
      $.getScript more_posts_url
    return
  return
```

posts controller:

```rb
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.js
        end
        @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15).order('created_at DESC')
```

Comment: Start by debugging it. Does the `scroll` event fire when you expect it to? use the browser's dev tools, add a breakpoint inside the callback. Does the the logic to detect the position at the bottom works right? same, use dev tools. Does the ajax request gets fired? check the network tab on dev tools. Does the controller respond with the correct response? check the rails logs, check the response on the browser's network tab. You can narrow it down a lot.

Answer (score 1):

need to change controller code to this

```
@posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15).order('created_at DESC')

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
end
```